# How to write JSON array in key:value format

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to get a JSON array form PHP output which fetches multiple values from the database and converts to JSON array. The PHP code is as follows:

```
php
$result = $conn->query("SELECT dbname FROM users ORDER BY dbname ASC");
//defined second array for dbnames' list
$dblist = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    //array_push($response['dblist'],$row['dbname']);
    $dblist = array('name'=>$row['dbname']);
}
$response['dblist'] = $dblist;
echo json_encode($response);
```

It gives the following output:

```
JSON
{"dblist":["a","arsod"]}
```

But, in order to extract values from JSON, the needed array is like:

```
json
{"dblist":{"name":"a","name":"arsod"}}
```

how can I achieve this? I want to fetch these values in android app.

Comment: `["name":"a","name":"arsod"]` <-- that's not actually a valid JSON - Arrays are numerically indexed, objects have text "keys" so it would have to be `{"name":"a","name":"arsod"}`

Comment: How is this supposed to work? The given code can never return any second `name` value, as you are simply overwriting `$dblist` in each iteration

Comment: @NicoHaase so how can i get it in android using `JSONArray`?

Comment: if its a collection of values, maybe you meant `$dblist['dblist'][] = ['name' => $row['dbname']]`; this should push values inside, not overwrite them every iteration

Comment: What makes you think that Android is related here after all? How do you want to access values under these duplicate key anyways?

Comment: Or maybe `$dblist['dblist']['name'][] = $row['dbname'];` would make sense. As said before, your current requirement isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT dbname FROM users ORDER BY dbname ASC");
$dblist = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $dblist[] = ['name'=>$row['dbname']];
}
$response['dblist'] = $dblist;

echo json_encode($reposne);
```

I basicaly added [] to $dbList so it looks like $dbList[] = ...

And with this, you will get a valid JSON that looks like this:

```
{"dblist":[{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"}]}
```

AS you requested output is not a good idea, since you will have duplicate keys in JSON

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code - what have you changed and why? Keep in mind that only an explanation helps others to learn from your answer

Comment: Added more info to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is a common mistake and basically only effects this row:

```php
$dblist = array('name'=>$row['dbname']);
```

where you set `$dblist` to a new created array in each iteration. What you want to do is **adding** a new entry to a list on every iteration

```php
$entry = array('name'=>$row['dbname']);
array_push($dblist, $entry);
```

Which is the same, as

```php
$entry[] = array('name'=>$row['dbname']);
```